# mySQL, PHP and mail() function

Tags: mysql

After joining two tables, i have realized that several rows have the same email address. I want to be able to mail the contents of all row that share thesame email address to that email address. i.e 

tablefood
username  |      email                                  |favoritefood
12raphael   |  12raphael@example.com     |noodles 
michael01   |  michael01@example.com    |lobster 
jordan606   |  jordan606 @example.com    |crabs 
bryant001  |  bryant001 @example.com    |chicken

freedrinks
food       |  drink1             |drink2
noodles   |  coke               |mineral water 
lobster    |  fanta               |coffee 
noodles   | ginger drink    |lemon drink 
chicken  |  ginger beer     |sprite

```
           $query=$conn->query("SELECT tablefood.username,
           tablefood.email,tablefood.favoritefood,freedrinks.drink1,
           freedrinks.drink2
           FROM tablefood
           INNER JOIN freedrinks
           ON tablefood.favoritefood=freedrinks.food");
```

After joining, we have something like this (for instance)
12raphael   |  12raphael@example.com     |noodles |coke               |mineral water 
12raphael   |  12raphael@example.com    |noodles   | ginger drink    |lemon drink

Manipulating the data and performing mail action i have something like the below code.

```
            if(!$query){
            echo "Error! Can not query database";
    die();
           }

           if($query->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

        $username=$row['username'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $food=$row['favoritefood'];
        $drink1=$row['drink1'];
        $drink2=$row['drink2'];

    $msg="Dear ".$username. "We are offering you one of the following 
    drinks for free ". $drink1." OR ".$drink2."\r\n";

        mail("$email","Freedrink",$msg);
```

My code works but it only sends mail per joined mySQL row i.e 
Dear 12Raphael,We are offering you one of the following 
        drinks for free  Coke Or Mineral Water
Dear 12Raphael,We are offering you one of the following 
        drinks for free  ginger drink Or lemon drink

What i want is to have it this way:

Dear 12Raphael,We are offering you one of the following 
        drinks for free coke or mineral water, ginger drink or lemon drink

How can i send all these contents at once so far the rows have the same email address.

This would really help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(!$query){
        echo "Error! Can not query database";
die();
       }
$drinks = '';

       if($query->num_rows>0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
if(empty($username)) {
    $username=$row['username'];
    $email=$row['email'];
    $food=$row['favoritefood'];
}
    $drink1=$row['drink1'];
    $drink2=$row['drink2'];       
    if (!empty($drinks)) $drinks .=", ";
    $drinks .= "$drink1 OR $drink2";
}
// after while cycle write this
$msg="Dear $username. We are offering you one of the following 
drinks for free $drinks\r\n";
mail("$email","Freedrink",$msg);
```